# About loop and implicit return in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm reading code of redmine. A part of the code is:

```
def funcA(projects)
  funcB(projects) do |project| #(1)
    s = funcC(...) #parameter masked
    s
  end
end
```

and the definition of `funcB` is:

```
def funcB(projects, &block)
  #do something
end
```

Assuming variable `projects` is an array of size 2,

1. What does the loop in place (1) do?
2. What will `funcA` return?

Comment: There is no loop here. This is simply a code block. https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/34-lambdas-and-blocks-in-ruby/lessons/78-blocks-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks,I understand now, it's like passing an anonymous function to funcB in place(1), right? And btw, there's "capture(project, &block)" in funcB, does the capture keyword means executing the anonymous function?

Comment: @realjin: that `capture` is yet another function which may do something with the block

Comment: `it's like passing an anonymous function to funcB in place(1), right?`. Exactly, blocks are anonymous functions. `capture` is not a built in ruby function but rather something user defined (AFAIK).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Oh, it seems that I need to get clear of what block means which seems different from anonymous function, thanks so much!

Comment: I removed the ruby-on-rails tag since this question is about plain old ruby and has nothing to do with rails.

Comment: @maxcal Yes, it looks like to be a build-in function in Ruby on Rails. Thanks!

Comment: @maxcal Yes you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what do the loop in place *(1) do?

It's not a loop (at least, not standard ruby loop). It is just a block passed to `funcB`. Same thing as with `Enumerable#each`.

> what will funcA returns?

Whatever `funcB` returns.